# What is the best way to deploy a https Node.js server using docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, ssl, nginx, https

I am learning about containers and docker for the first time. I have successfully deployed a node.js application however, I am am not sure how to setup HTTPS.

Should I deploy a SSL cert with the docker image, or is it better practice to use a reverse proxy such as nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Use nginx.
It will make your solution flexible and extensible without need to write single line of code.

Reasoning:

1) if you decide to go with LetsEncrypt then you will need to restart (or hot reload) your SSL transport layer.
Implementing hot reload of certificate in node.js (while keeping websocket connections active) would require extra effort but could be accomplished with single bash command (launched from certbot hook)

```
systemctl reload nginx
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

2) it is rare when the single domain provides API only interface to the world.
Most likely you will need to serve static files for front-end as well. 
It does not make sense to write code to serve static files at node.js side when nginx can do it for free (i.e. without writing any line of code).

3) If you decide to extend your service with extra technologies like usage of php/java/whatever else for backend you will just need to add several lines of code into nginx configuration instead of implementation of request forwarding to other services.

4) ...

@all, Feel free to extend reasons so people who come later would see all benefits of such architecture approach.

So when you need to make architecture decision follow [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) principles.